# Has anyone tried to compile OpenBLAS to Webassembly using clang/emcc?

Tags: makefile, clang, webassembly, openblas, emcc

In the OpenBLAS root directory on a linux system, with emcc sdk already loaded by (in the emsdk directory, `source ./emsdk_env.sh`)

I was trying to use emcc to compile OpenBLAS by
`make CC=emcc NOFORTRAN=1 HOSTCC=emcc BINARY=64 libs`, 
but it complained about cpuid.S.

I understand that it was a assembly file, so instead, I also tried to use clang:
`make CC="clang --target=wasm32" NOFORTRAN=1 HOSTCC=clang BINARY=64 libs`.
Then I got an error saying:

> **fatal error:** error in backend: 64-bit WebAssembly (wasm64) is not
>   currently supported.

Does this mean that, one cannot use OpenBLAS to create a .a lib for static linking for Webassembly x64 usage? Has anybody got luck on similar usage? Thanks in advance!

I am using clang version 10.0.0, emcc version 1.39.13, and openBLAS latest code (0.3.9.dev.a).

Answer (score 0):

The OpenBLAS repo contains some discussions on how to compile it for WebAssembly, using a "RISCV64_GENERIC" target:

- https://github.com/OpenMathLib/OpenBLAS/issues/3640
- https://github.com/OpenMathLib/OpenBLAS/issues/4023

Here's a small compile script I use with emcc:

```
(system) sevagh@pop-os:~/repos/freemdx-lab$ cat openblas_wasm_build.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# we use OpenBLAS which purportedly can compile to WASM:
#   - https://github.com/OpenMathLib/OpenBLAS/issues/3640
#   - https://github.com/OpenMathLib/OpenBLAS/issues/4023
cd vendor/OpenBLAS
make clean
make CC=emcc HOSTCC=gcc \
    TARGET=RISCV64_GENERIC \
        ONLY_CBLAS=1 NOFORTRAN=1 NO_LAPACK=1 NO_LAPACKE=1 \
        C_LAPACK=0 BUILD_WITHOUT_LAPACK=1 USE_THREAD=0 \
        BUILD_BFLOAT16=0 BUILD_COMPLEX16=0 BUILD_COMPLEX=0 \
         CFLAGS="-O3 -ffast-math -msimd128 -mavx"
```

However, again from those GitHub issues, the discussion boils around the lack of WASM intrinsics, and we can't easily use the SSE or AVX OpenBLAS, that Emscripten would be able to translate to WASM intrinsics, since the SSE or AVX code has inline assembly written that can't be translated.